# View's getWidth() and getHeight() returns 0

Tags: java, android, android-layout, getter

I am creating all of the elements in my android project dynamically. I am trying to get the width and height of a button so that I can rotate that button around. I am just trying to learn how to work with the android language. However, it returns 0.

I did some research and I saw that it needs to be done somewhere other than in the `onCreate()` method. If someone can give me an example of how to do it, that would be great.

Here is my current code:

```
package com.animation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class AnimateScreen extends Activity {


//Called when the activity is first created.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

    Button bt = new Button(this);
    bt.setText(String.valueOf(bt.getWidth()));
   
    RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(0,360,bt.getWidth() / 2,bt.getHeight() / 2);
    ra.setDuration(3000L);
    ra.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    ra.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    ra.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    bt.startAnimation(ra);
    
    ll.addView(bt,layoutParams);
    
    setContentView(ll);
}
```

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You are calling `getWidth()` too early. The UI has not been sized and laid out on the screen yet.

I doubt you want to be doing what you are doing, anyway -- widgets being animated do not change their clickable areas, and so the button will still respond to clicks in the original orientation regardless of how it has rotated.

That being said, you can use a [dimension resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) to define the button size, then reference that dimension resource from your layout file and your source code, to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually found another solution that worked for me, but this is a nice detail to know.

Comment: ngreenwood6, what is your other solution?

Comment: @Andrew - if you want negreenwood6 to be notified of your follow up, you have to start your message like I did to you (I think first three letters is enough) - CommonsWare gets notified automatically, since he wrote this response, but ngreen doesn't unless you address them.

Comment: @Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  //Here you can get the size!
 }

Comment: @ngreenwood6 So what was your solution?

Comment: Use this listener to get size, when is your screen ready. view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {}

Comment: lol, he just ran out with the confirmation of impossibility, then people here are in dead-lock.

Answer (score 988):

The basic problem is, that you have to wait for the drawing phase for the actual measurements (especially with dynamic values like `wrap_content` or `match_parent`), but usually this phase hasn't been finished up to `onResume()`. So you need a workaround for waiting for this phase. There are different possible solutions to this:

### 1. Listen to Draw/Layout Events: ViewTreeObserver

A ViewTreeObserver gets fired for different drawing events. Usually the [`OnGlobalLayoutListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) is what you want for getting the measurement, so the code in the listener will be called after the layout phase, so the measurements are ready:

```java
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        view.getHeight(); //height is ready
    }
});
```

*Note*: The listener will be immediately removed because otherwise it will fire on every layout event. If you have to support apps *SDK Level < 16* use this to unregister the listener:

```java
public void removeGlobalOnLayoutListener (ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener victim)
```

### 2. Add a runnable to the layout queue: View.post()

Not very well known and my favourite solution. Basically just use the View's post method with your own runnable. This basically queues your code *after* the view's measure, layout, etc. as stated by [Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298575/romain-guy):

> The UI event queue will process events in order. After
> setContentView() is invoked, the event queue will contain a message
> asking for a relayout, so anything you post to the queue will happen
> after the layout pass

Example:

```java
final View view=...;
...
view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.getHeight(); //height is ready
            }
        });
```

The advantage over `ViewTreeObserver`:

- your code is only executed once, and you don't have to disable the Observer after execution which can be a hassle
- less verbose syntax

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3602144/774398
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3948036/774398

### 3. Overwrite Views's onLayout Method

This is only practical in certain situation when the logic can be encapsulated in the view itself, otherwise this is a quite verbose and cumbersome syntax.

```java
view = new View(this) {
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        view.getHeight(); //height is ready
    }
};
```

Also mind, that onLayout will be called many times, so be considerate what you do in the method, or disable your code after the first time

### 4. Check if has been through layout phase

If you have code that is executing multiple times while creating the UI you could use the following support v4 lib method:

```java
View viewYouNeedHeightFrom = ...
...
if(ViewCompat.isLaidOut(viewYouNeedHeightFrom)) {
   viewYouNeedHeightFrom.getHeight();
}
```

> Returns true if view has been through at least one layout since it was
> last attached to or detached from a window.

### Additional: Getting statically defined measurements

If it suffices to just get the statically defined height/width, you can just do this with:

- [`View.getMeasuredWidth()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredWidth())
- [`View.getMeasuredHeigth()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredHeight())

But mind you, that this might be different to the actual width/height after drawing. The Javadoc describes the difference in more detail:

> The size of a view is expressed with a width and a height. A view
> actually possess two pairs of width and height values.
>
> The first pair is known as measured width and measured height. These
> dimensions define how big a view wants to be within its parent (see
> Layout for more details.) The measured dimensions can be obtained by
> calling getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight().
>
> The second pair is simply known as width and height, or sometimes
> drawing width and drawing height. These dimensions define the actual
> size of the view on screen, at drawing time and after layout. These
> values may, but do not have to, be different from the measured width
> and height. The width and height can be obtained by calling getWidth()
> and getHeight().

Comment: onLayout was the key for me to detect the display of my view and setting the height of it based on its new width :) 
I've just added a flag to disable the called if not needed it anymore

Comment: I'm using the view.post in a fragment.  I need to measure the view whose parent's height is 0dp and has a weight set.  Everything I try returns a height of zero (I've also tried the global layout listener).  When I put the view.post code in onViewCreated with a delay of 125, it works, but not without the delay.  Ideas?

Comment: too bad you can only upvote an answer once, really good explanation. I had a problem with a view rotation if I quit my app and restarted it from the recent apps. If I swiped it from there and did a fresh restart everything was fine. The view.post() saved my day!

Comment: Great Solution , but the code inside onGlobalLayout ,, is called again and again and again .... why this happen ???

Comment: Its explained in the answer "But beware that this will be called everytime something gets layouted (e.g if you set a view invisible or similar) so don't forget to remove this listener if you don't need it anymore with:"

Comment: The second one is just perfect for me. I need one height only so it's the simplest way. Thanks, dude! :)

Comment: Thanks. I usually use View.post() (2nd method), but if it is called from a background thread it sometimes doesn't work. So, don't forget to write `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...}`. Currently I use a variation of the 1st method: `addOnLayoutChangeListener`. Don't forget to remove it then inside: removeOnLayoutChangeListener. It works from background thread as well.

Comment: View.post() is some voodoo magic! Thank you, worked for me when trying to get the viewed width of a horizontalscrollview.

Comment: Unfortunately for me 'View.post()' is not working all the time. I have 2 projects which are very similar. In one project it's working, on the other is  not working. :(. In both situation I call the method from 'onCreate()' method from an Activity. Any suggestion why?

Comment: I find the issue. In one project the view has `android:visibility="gone"`, and on the other project the visibility property was`invisible`. If the visibility is `gone` the width will be always 0.

Comment: You could also have added `onWindowFocusChanged()` as 5th option

Comment: @Jack I don't see onWindowFocusChanged() as a good solution because it only works with activities and not really the correct callback

Comment: @AdrianBuciuman. `Width = 0` for `gone` is correct. This is the same as inspected in the layout inspector. visibility gone would not render the view, it is completely hidden. It is impossible to get any height or width for "gone" view.

Answer (score 269):

We can use

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  //Here you can get the size!
 }
```

Comment: so how can we work in Fragments ? this works only in Activity ?

Comment: This should do the thing but its should not be the answer. A user wants to get dimensions in any point of time instead of getting drawn on the window. Also this method gets called multiple time or every time when there's a change(View hide, gone, adding new views etc..) in the window. So use it carefully :)

Comment: This is a hack and it seems like using the ViewTreeObserver would be better.

Comment: Don't mean to sound rude, but leaving an auto generated comment (especially in 2 lines of code) doesn't give much confidence that you actually know what you are doing.

Comment: Unluckily, it didn't work for me. Trying viewTreeObserver worked for me.

Comment: nice! I've used `setOnFocusChangeListener` to get the width and height, and worked

Answer (score 118):

I used this solution, which I think is better than onWindowFocusChanged(). If you open a DialogFragment, then rotate the phone, onWindowFocusChanged will be called only when the user closes the dialog):

```
    yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Ensure you call it only once :
            yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

            // Here you can get the size :)
        }
    });
```

Edit : as removeGlobalOnLayoutListener is deprecated, you should now do :

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {

    // Ensure you call it only once :
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
    else {
        yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }

    // Here you can get the size :)
}
```

Comment: this is by far the best solution! because it works also on dynamic solutions where the width and height are not known and calculated. i.e. in a relative layout based on the positions/sizes of other elements. Well done!

Comment: This requires API 16 or higher (Jelly bean)

Comment: It does NOT REQUIRE API 16! The only issue is method removeGlobalOnLayoutListener deprecated from API 16, but there is simple solution compatible with all api levels - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189525/ongloballayoutlistener-deprecation-and-compatibility

Comment: If you need to remove the listener so that doesn’t call itself many times and you having issues with different APIs, I recommend you to set a false boolean at the head of the class and then after capturing the values set it to true so that it doesn’t capture the values again.

Comment: If you remove the listener after the first run you might get wrong dimensions: 02-14 10:18:53.786 15063-15063/PuzzleFragment: height: 1647 width: 996
02-14 10:18:53.985 15063-15063/PuzzleFragment: height: 1500 width: 996

Comment: What is `container` ? Is it the same as `yourView` ? According to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16189525/) , it is.

Comment: This is best solution! Thanks

Comment: This appears to not always work. The `OnPreDrawListener` proposed in another answer works. On the other hand using `OnPreDrawListener` isn't a good solution...

Answer (score 91):

If you need to get width of some widget before it is displayed on screen, you can use getMeasuredWidth() or getMeasuredHeight().

```
myImage.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int width = myImage.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = myImage.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: For some reason, this was the only answer that worked for me - thanks!

Comment: Same to me, the simplest solution, that worked to me

Comment: Work like a charm!

Comment: @CommonsWare how does this solution give the height and width before the view tree observer on global layouts callback, an explanation would be helpful.

Comment: It's 2021 this method solved my problem

Comment: Thanks! In my case `view.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)` helped.

Comment: thank you, worked for me

Comment: This worked for me in 2023. Great

Answer (score 76):

As Ian states in [this Android Developers thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a53372e1c468ef01?pli=1):

> Anyhow, the deal is that layout of the
>   contents of a window happens
>   *after* all the elements are constructed and added to their parent
>   views.  It has to be this way, because
>   until you know what components a View
>   contains, and what they contain, and
>   so on, there's no sensible way you can
>   lay it out.
>
> Bottom line, if you call getWidth()
>   etc. in a constructor, it will return
>   zero.  The procedure is to create all
>   your view elements in the constructor,
>   then wait for your View's
>   onSizeChanged() method to be called --
>   that's when you first find out your
>   real size, so that's when you set up
>   the sizes of your GUI elements.
>
> Be aware too that onSizeChanged() is
>   sometimes called with parameters of
>   zero -- check for this case, and
>   return immediately (so you don't get a
>   divide by zero when calculating your
>   layout, etc.).  Some time later it
>   will be called with the real values.

Comment: onSizeChanged worked for me. onWindowFocusedChanged doesn't get called in my custom view.

Comment: this looks a good solution, but what should i always create my custom view to override onSizeChanged method?

Comment: `Bottom line, if you call getWidth() etc. in a constructor, it will return zero.` that's a bingo. The root of my issues.

Comment: I suggest this solution for fragments, because some other solutions return 0 in my case.

Answer (score 35):

I would rather use [OnPreDrawListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener) instead of [addOnGlobalLayoutListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver#addOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)), since it is called a bit earlier than other listeners.

```
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw()
        {
            if (view.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive())
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            
            // put your code here
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Adjusted the code according to comment of @Pang. onPreDraw method should return true to proceed with the current drawing pass.

Comment: Note that `return false` means [*to **cancel** the current drawing pass*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html#onPreDraw()). To proceed, `return true` instead.

Answer (score 33):

AndroidX has multiple extension functions that help you with this kind of work, inside `androidx.core.view`

You need to use Kotlin for this.

The one that best fits here is `doOnLayout`:

> Performs the given action when this view is laid out. If the view has been laid out and it has not requested a layout, the action will be performed straight away otherwise, the action will be performed after the view is next laid out.
>
> The action will only be invoked once on the next layout and then removed.

In your example:

```
bt.doOnLayout {
    val ra = RotateAnimation(0,360,it.width / 2,it.height / 2)
    // more code
}
```

Dependency: `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0`

Comment: This is the only correct answer. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-room-release/core/ktx/src/main/java/androidx/core/view/View.kt#65

Comment: these extensions are really important and useful

Comment: Thank you so much. it look like `doOnLayout` is better than `addOnGlobalLayoutListener`. In my case, I change the theme of application in a Fragment of ViewPager. After I changed the theme, `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` in `onViewCreated` of another Fragment fired and return 0. 
With `doOnLayout`, this problem won't happened. `doOnLayout` is not fired until I come back to the Fragment

Answer (score 12):

A Kotlin Extension to observe on the global layout and perform a given task when height is ready dynamically.

Usage:

```
view.height { Log.i("Info", "Here is your height:" + it) }
```

Implementation:

```
fun <T : View> T.height(function: (Int) -> Unit) {
    if (height == 0)
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                function(height)
            }
        })
    else function(height)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It happens because the view needs more time to be inflated. So instead of calling `view.width` and `view.height` on the main thread, you should use `view.post { ... }` to make sure that your `view` has already been inflated. In Kotlin:

```
view.post{width}
view.post{height}
```

In Java you can also call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods in a `Runnable` and pass the `Runnable` to `view.post()` method.

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.getWidth(); 
            view.getHeight();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This isn't correct answer as the view might not be measured and laid out when the posted code executes. It would be an edge case, but `.post` doesn't guarantee the view to be laid out.

Comment: This answer was great and worked for me. Thank you very much Ehsan

Comment: Be careful that ```getWidth()``` is measured in **pixels**, not **dp**. I lost too much time with this little detail

Answer (score 5):

One liner if you are using [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) & [RxBindings](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding). Similar approach without the boilerplate. This also solves the hack to suppress warnings as in the answer by [Tim Autin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15578844/245495).

```
RxView.layoutChanges(yourView).take(1)
      .subscribe(aVoid -> {
           // width and height have been calculated here
      });
```

This is it. No need to be unsubscribe, even if never called.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this helps someone:

Create an extension function for the View class

> filename: ViewExt.kt

```
fun View.afterLayout(what: () -> Unit) {
    if(isLaidOut) {
        what.invoke()
    } else {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                what.invoke()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This can then be used on any view with:

```
view.afterLayout {
    do something with view.height
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using Kotlin**

```
  customView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

            override fun onGlobalLayout() {

                if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    customView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                }
                else {
                    customView.viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)
                }

                // Here you can get the size :)
                viewWidth = customView.width
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

Height and width are zero because view has not been created by the time you are requesting it's height and width . 
One simplest solution is

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.getHeight(); //height is ready
            view.getWidth(); //width is ready
        }
    });
```

This method is good as compared to other methods as it is short and crisp.

Answer (score 2):

Answer with `post` is incorrect, because the size might not be recalculated.
Another important thing is that **the view and all it ancestors must be visible**. For that I use a property `View.isShown`.

Here is my kotlin function, that can be placed somewhere in utils:

```
fun View.onInitialized(onInit: () -> Unit) {
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            if (isShown) {
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                onInit()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And the usage is:

```
myView.onInitialized {
    Log.d(TAG, "width is: " + myView.width)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## For Kotlin:

I have faced a production crash due to use `view.height`/ `view.width` which lead to `NaN` while I was using `View.post()` which sometimes view diemsions returned with 0 value.

So,

Use `view.doOnPreDraw { // your action here}` which is:

- `OneShotPreDrawListener` so it called only one time.
- Implements `OnPreDrawListener` which make sure view is layouted and measured

Answer (score 1):

well , you can use `addOnLayoutChangeListener`

you can use it in `onCreate` in `Activity`  or `onCreateView` in `Fragment`

@Edit
dont forget to remove it because in some cases its trigger infinite loop

```kotlin
myView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(object : View.OnLayoutChangeListener{
                override fun onLayoutChange(
                    v: View?, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int, oldLeft: Int, oldTop: Int, oldRight: Int, oldBottom: Int
                ) {
                    if (v?.width > 0 && v?.height > 0){
                        // do something
                        Log.i(TAG, "view : ${view.width}")
                        // remove after finish
                        v?.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this) 
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

Cleanest way of doing this is using post method of view :

kotlin:

```
  view.post{
      var width = view.width
      var height = view.height
  }
```

Java:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int width = view.getWidth();
        int height = view.getHeight();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Gone views returns 0 as height if app in background.
This my code (1oo% works)

```
fun View.postWithTreeObserver(postJob: (View, Int, Int) -> Unit) {
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            val heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            measure(widthSpec, heightSpec)
            postJob(this@postWithTreeObserver, measuredWidth, measuredHeight)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)
            } else {
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to wait for view will be drawn. For this purpose use OnPreDrawListener. Kotlin example:

```
val preDrawListener = object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {

                override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                    view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)

                    // code which requires view size parameters

                    return true
                }
            }

            view.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(preDrawListener)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I can't get a view's height by post or by addOnGlobalLayoutListener, it's always 0. Because my view is in a fragment, and the fragment is the second tab in MainActivity. when I open MainActivity, I enter the first tab, so the second tab doesn't show on the screen. But onGlobalLayout() or post() function still has a callback.

I get the view's height when the second fragment is visible on the screen. And this time I get the correct height.

Comment: First, your answer is an own opinion. In addition, a good and accepted answer was given 8 years ago. Therefore, your answer is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I try to solve my problem with the above best answer. But it did not work.  So I Offered another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
imageView.size { width, height ->
            //your code
        }
```

View extention:

```
fun <T : View> T.size(function: (Int, Int) -> Unit) {
    if (isLaidOut && height != 0 && width != 0) {
        function(width, height)
    } else {
        if (height == 0 || width == 0) {
            var onLayoutChangeListener: View.OnLayoutChangeListener? = null
            var onGlobalLayoutListener: ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener? = null

            onGlobalLayoutListener = object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (isShown) {
                        removeOnLayoutChangeListener(onLayoutChangeListener)
                        viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                        function(width, height)
                    }
                }
            }

            onLayoutChangeListener = object : View.OnLayoutChangeListener {
                override fun onLayoutChange(
                    v: View?,
                    left: Int,
                    top: Int,
                    right: Int,
                    bottom: Int,
                    oldLeft: Int,
                    oldTop: Int,
                    oldRight: Int,
                    oldBottom: Int
                ) {
                    val width = v?.width ?: 0
                    val height = v?.height ?: 0
                    if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
                        // remove after finish
                        viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener)
                        v?.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this)
                        function(width, height)
                    }
                }
            }

            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener)
            addOnLayoutChangeListener(onLayoutChangeListener)
        } else {
            function(width, height)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public final class ViewUtils {

    public interface ViewUtilsListener {
        void onDrawCompleted();
    }

    private ViewUtils() {
    }

    public static void onDraw(View view, ViewUtilsListener listener) {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (view.getHeight() != 0 && view.getWidth() != 0) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onDrawCompleted();
                    }
                    view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

you can use like this ;

```
ViewUtils.onDraw(view, new ViewUtils.ViewUtilsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawCompleted() {
                    int width = view.getWidth();
                    int height = view.getHeight();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private val getWidth: Int
    get() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
            val windowMetrics =windowManager.currentWindowMetrics
            val bounds = windowMetrics.bounds
            var adWidthPixels = View.width.toFloat()
            if (adWidthPixels == 0f) {
                adWidthPixels = bounds.width().toFloat()
            }
            val density = resources.displayMetrics.density
            val adWidth = (adWidthPixels / density).toInt()
            return adWidth
        } else {
            val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
            val outMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
            display.getMetrics(outMetrics)
            val density = outMetrics.density
            var adWidthPixels = View.width.toFloat()
            if (adWidthPixels == 0f) {
                adWidthPixels = outMetrics.widthPixels.toFloat()
            }
            val adWidth = (adWidthPixels / density).toInt()
            return adWidth
        }
    }
```

replace (View) with the view you want to measure

Answer (score 0):

Just came around this old question. Basically, the solution is to wait for the View to be measured and "drawn". You can achieve that by implementing some late lifecycle callback (e.g. `onGlobalLayout`), but I found a simpler solution that works well for me: just wait for the attributes to become non-zero.

The caveat here is that you mustn't block the UI thread while waitig. It's very easy to achieve if you use Kotlin Coroutines:

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
       
        coroutineScope.launch {
            while (imgBarcode.width == 0 || imgBarcode.height == 0) {
                MyLogger.d("waiting for ImageView to get its eventual size")
                delay(50)
            }

            val barcodeBitmap = generateBarcodeUseCase.generateBarcode(
                data, imgBarcode.width, imgBarcode.height
            )

            imgBarcode.setImageBitmap(barcodeBitmap)
        }
    }
```

If you don't use Coroutines, you'll need to use e.g. `Handler.postDelayed()` calls to implement the same feature.

Answer (score -1):

This is a little old, but was having trouble with this myself (needing to animate objects in a fragment when it is created).  This solution worked for me, I believe it is self explanatory.

```
class YourFragment: Fragment() {
    var width = 0
    var height = 0


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_winner_splash, container, false)
    container?.width.let {
        if (it != null) {
            width = it
        }
    }
    container?.height.let {
        if (it != null) {
            height = it
        }
    }
    
    return root
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're worried about overworking the onDraw method, you can always set the dimension as null during construction and then only set the dimension inside of onDraw if it's null.

That way you're not really doing any work inside onDraw

```
class myView(context:Context,attr:AttributeSet?):View(context,attr){
var height:Float?=null


override fun onDraw(canvas:Canvas){
    if (height==null){height=this.height.toFloat()}
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Set *layoutParams*:

   ```
   view.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, 0)
   ```
2. In the *doOnLayout* method you can get the size of the view:

   ```
   view.doOnLayout { view -> view.width | view.height }
   ```